# При сворачивании окна браузера, останавливается выполнение скрипта

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Ситуация следующая: есть однооконное приложение (игра с вращающимися барабанами), которая штатно работает если вкладка браузера, в которой работает это приложение, не теряет фокуса. Но стоит свернуть окно браузера (либо переключится на другую вкладку), а потом вернуться обратно, то приложение останавливается. Причем происходит это не моментально, а через разные промежутки времени (от нескольких секунд до нескольких минут), и на одном и том же цикле вращения.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать для решения этой проблемы? Приму во внимание любые ответы.

Анимация построена с использованием `requestAnimationFrame()`.

```
var lastTime = Date.now();
function main() {

  var now = Date.now();
  var dt = Math.min((now - lastTime), 20) / 1000.0;

  update(dt);
  render();
  lastTime = now;

  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
```

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с [тестами](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16033979/4041128) и [возможным решением](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17224661/4041128)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проверяет на `window.document.hasFocus`.
Можно решить проблему, выполнив скрипт:

```
window.document.hasFocus = function() {return true;}
```

Выполнить можно, написав UserScript или расширение, в зависимости от браузера, либо просто в адресной строке (если нет необходимости выполнять его до старта скрипта страницы)

Comment: забыл уточнить, приложение написано мной, и я не делаю никаких проверок на потерю фокуса, но вот проблема такая почему-то возникает. Никакие ошибки в консоль при этом не выводятся.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему вы пишите, что-то вроде игры. Браузер старается оптимизировать работу рендеринга страницы, поэтому requestAnimationFrame не вызывается когда вкладка не активна. Запускайте заново рендеринг при фокусе страницы:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    main();
});
```

Comment: Да, игра заводится с "толкача". в функции  update(dt) у меня идет обновление в несколько раздельных последовательных этапов. Переход на следующий этап выбирается в зависимости от того произошло ли какое-либо событие в игре. Так вот заметил, что остановка происходит на одном и том же этапе. И если следующий этап запускать "в ручную" вызовом соответствующего метода, то все продолжается и работает дальше как надо. Единственная проблема - игра может отработать несколько полных циклов, проходя все этапы и в неактивной вкладке, а потом в какой-то случайный момент тормознуться.

Comment: Не могу сказать в какой момент браузер может решить остановить скрипт, возможно оценивается использование процессорного времени, время пройденное после ухода с вкладки, так навскидку дать ответ на вопрос "в какой момент браузер решит остановить скрипт" не получится. Вообще советую при потере фокуса все ставить на паузу и не беспокоится по поводу того в какой момент игра "застрянет".

Comment: Согласен, так было бы оптимальнее всего. Если б я раньше мог предвидеть такое поведение, то делал бы обновление всех модулей от одного тикера. А то у меня еще звуки есть, которые затухают по setTimeout(а само затухание сделано с использованием setInterval). Теперь все это добро просто так не остановить в нужный момент...

Comment: Я бы посоветовал переписать, сделать менеджер работающий со звуками и через который можно разом замьютить все, я думаю вам придется к этому прийти т.к. иначе это уже не решить.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась отказом от requestAnimationFrame и обновлением через  setTimeout, который работает в ворекре. (Помогло вот это кастомное решение https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer). Единственная неприятность здесь - это то что пропала плавность в анимации(появились подергивания). Может кто знает как добиться плавности?